# Any workarounds to this IE8 bug?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Is there any workaround to the IE8 bug where some elements seem to collapse the vertical margins and reset it when hover over the element?

You can test the bug at: http://www.gilbertybolona.com/seguros/generales/

And this is a screenshot: [d.pr/Plf8](http://d.pr/Plf8)

All of the elements should be equally separated.

Comment: Screenshot: http://d.pr/Plf8 - Wasn't able to post two links as a spam prevention :S

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the same behaviour with CUFON turned off?

I tried to isolate the issue and can't get the bug to occur. See here: http://jsbin.com/uceto4

You could try adding these to the styles for the dt.

`position:relative; display:inline;`

these can fix some IE bugs to do with hover / margins.

You could also try typeface.js and see if that does the same thing.

Comment: I also wasn't able to reproduce on the jsbin you posted, but I tried removing the cufon on my webpage and the same bug appeared also tried the css properties you specified but the result was the same. I guess it is some crazy IE8 bug.